# Which hooks for WooCommerce stock saved or updated

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, hook-woocommerce

I am creating an event ticketing WordPress theme and I am using WooCommerce and [Advanced custom fields *(ACF)*](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugins.

I want to update a custom post type called event. With the stock of a specific ticket. That way my client does not need to look at the woo-commerce products page but can just simply open an "Event"

I tried using the `update_post_meta` hook but that only works when an admin updates the product in the admin tool. Not with a new order.

```
function sync_product_stock( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    $postType = get_post_type( $post_id );
    if ($postType  == 'product' ) {
        if ( $meta_key == '_stock' ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
            $eventId = $product->get_attribute( 'event_id' );
            $productName = $product->get_name();
            if ($productName.include('Early Bird')) {
                update_field( 'event_early_bird_group_event_early_bird_amount_of_tickets', $meta_value, $eventId );
            } else if ($productName.include('Regular')) {
                update_field( 'event_regular_group_event_regular_amount_of_tickets', $meta_value, $eventId );
            } else if ($productName.include('Member')) {
                // nothing needs to be updated
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'sync_product_stock', 10, 4);
```

How can I get notified when the `_stock` field is updated? (I don't want to handle the stock-keeping myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. Try the following using woocommerce hooks:

```
// On processed update product stock event
add_action( 'woocommerce_updated_product_stock', 'wc_updated_product_stock_callback' );
// On admin single product creation/update
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wc_updated_product_stock_callback' );
// On admin single product variation creation/update
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'wc_updated_product_stock_callback' );
function wc_updated_product_stock_callback( $product_id ) {
    // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    $stock_qty    = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $event_id     = $product->get_attribute('event_id');
    $product_name = $product->get_name();

    if ( strpos($product_name, 'Early Bird') !== false ) {
        update_field( 'event_early_bird_group_event_early_bird_amount_of_tickets', $stock_qty, $event_id );
    } elseif ( strpos($product_name, 'Regular') !== false ) {
        update_field( 'event_regular_group_event_regular_amount_of_tickets', $stock_qty, $event_id );
    } elseif ( strpos($product_name, 'Member') !== false ) {
        // nothing needs to be updated
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.